# Java Spark - Multiple value check on Spark dataframe column while using when condition

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe where I am creating a column and populating values based on conditions in other columns.

```
List<String> new_lst = new ArrayList<String>();
new_lst.add("value 1");
new_lst.add("value_2");

df_new = df.withColumn("new_column",functions.when(functions.col("col_1").equalTo("A")
.and(functions.col("col_2").isin(new_lst.stream().toArray(String[]::new)),functions.col("col_3"))
.otherwise(functions.col("col_1");
```

When i use the above i get a warning that

> Confusing argument new_lst.stream().toArray(String[]::new, unclear if
>   a varargs or non-varargs call is desired

My requirement is that i am creating a column called new_column by check if col_1 is equal to A and 
col_2 has value_1 and value_2 then i have to get values from col_3, else from col_1.

Kindly let me know the best way to implement this in java spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe api is as below-

```
def isin(list: Any*): Column = withExpr { In(expr, list.map(lit(_).expr)) }
```

Its basically `Array<Object>` from java.
Try below approach- use either `isInCollection(Iterable<>)` or `isin(Object[])`

```java
 List<String> new_lst = new ArrayList<>();
        new_lst.add("value_1");
        new_lst.add("value_2");

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.range(1).withColumn("col_1", lit("A"))
                .withColumn("col_2", lit("value_2"))
                .withColumn("col_3", lit("C"));
        Dataset<Row> df_new = df.withColumn("new_column",functions.when(functions.col("col_1").equalTo("A")
                .and(functions.col("col_2").isInCollection(new_lst)), functions.col("col_3"))
                .otherwise(functions.col("col_1"))
        );
        df_new.show(false);

        /**
         * +---+-----+-------+-----+----------+
         * |id |col_1|col_2  |col_3|new_column|
         * +---+-----+-------+-----+----------+
         * |0  |A    |value_2|C    |C         |
         * +---+-----+-------+-----+----------+
         */
        df.withColumn("new_column",functions.when(functions.col("col_1").equalTo("A")
                .and(functions.col("col_2").isin((Object[]) new_lst.toArray())),functions.col("col_3"))
                .otherwise(functions.col("col_1"))).show(false);
        /**
         * +---+-----+-------+-----+----------+
         * |id |col_1|col_2  |col_3|new_column|
         * +---+-----+-------+-----+----------+
         * |0  |A    |value_2|C    |C         |
         * +---+-----+-------+-----+----------+
         */
```

Comment: I used .isInCollection() and it worked as expected. Thank you